# Dynamic loaded page doesn't re-bind the JS code

Tags: jquery

I have that scenario. I load dynamically the `Page A` which contains some JS code. Inside that page, I can dynamically load another Page B (which can be also dynamically removed by using `fadeOut` effect and `.remove()` function)

The Page B contains a jQUery's UI `datepicker` plugin (and also some other plugins).

And here's the thing: if I load the `Page B`, the `datepicker` is initialized properly, but if I remove that `Page B` and re-load it, that `datepicker` is not being initialized. Why ?

I'm using the `.datepicker("destroy")` function and then `.datepicker({...})` inside the `Page B` but without any effect.

Comment: Is there any js error? All browsers?

Comment: Because you're dynamically loading content the JS for that page has run and completed. Have a look at jQuery's on() method http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Diego - I've checked it on Chrome and Firefox. I don't get any errors

Answer (score 1):

try importing your B js in the A js like this:

```
$.getScript("yourOwnPath/theB.js", function() {
        });
```